# Accidentally dragged a font's typeface out of the font dialog and "deleted" it

Tags: xcode, font, dialog

When I was trying to change the font in my xcode, I accidentally dragged a typeface out of the dialog with the mouse, causing the typeface to disappear from the fonts dialog forever.

[image]

As you can see, Menlo Regular is gone, (Italic too, because I couldn't help myself, damn me) I can't select it anymore. Funnily enough, you can't drag the typeface out of the window on another machine here. How would I get it back?

For clarification, the typeface is still available on the system, just not in that dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the hack typeface and managed to resolve the issue.

You have to go to `/Users/>>your_username<</Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes`
and then open a *.dvtcolortheme file.

This file has xml syntax. There you'll find string elements with the current font, typeface and size.

Select all font and typeface and change it with your deleted one.

[image: example scheme file]

Save the file and restart & check your Xcode.
Your missing typefaces should be there again.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the font itself, `/System/Library/Fonts/Menlo.ttc`, you should be able to open Font Book and just drag the `Menlo.ttc` onto the application window and it'll add back the font for you.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work. I did manage to get the Regular typeface back by putting it under a new collection in Font Book, but it's still quite a silly solution.